# EndpointNotFoundException on client machine

Tags: wpf, wcf, nettcpbinding

My WCF Service is hosted under net.tcpbinding and in case it is not running when client makes a call to its methods but let me tell you our some of clients get access and some of not. i even check antivirus setting and firewall setting for each client but haven't came up with right answer , client gets the EndpointNotFoundException with this message:

There was no endpoint listening...

i have check the path of service there is no mistake in path. and in my nettcp service based on window credential type and enabletcpportsharing is also on.

Still searching for right solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Try running netstat -t -a and see if you can find your TCP port running and in a listening status on command prompt

Comment: it's in  sync_state (myservice:808 sync_state) but not establishing connection on most of window xp machine. any idea how to established connectin with TCP

Comment: After trying telnet (IP Address of app server) Port. so i can understand it's blocking by window firewall or router firewall. if telnet open window from client machine that's mean its working and if not opening in window then call Network administrator to open that port

Comment: Try disabling the firewall to see if you can access that. Make sure to disable the firewall only if your company/organisation has a firewall on.

Comment: yes it's already disabled, my question was my service is working for some client and not working for some client so i was confused why it so happening but now i am telneting my service at client machine where endpointexception is occured that's confirm me whether port is not blocking by client machine firewall or client side router firewall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying telnet (IP Address of app server) Port. so i can understand it's blocking by window firewall or router firewall. if telnet open window from client machine that's mean its working and if not opening in window then call Network administrator to open that port

Eg. telnet xxx.xx.xx.xx 80 in command prompt